# Active Directory query on Power Shell with input file

Tags: powershell, input, active-directory

I have an issue with Active Directory.

This is the scenario:

1. I have to perform some queries on a user set.
2. I have no access to graphical tool, only to Power Shell.
3. Those users are listed on a csv, one per row.
4. For those user, I have not the `SamAccountName`, but `Name` field, so their names and surnames.

So, I have to give this set as input to my queries.
I searched on google and I found this link, which has been very useful for most basic queries:
http://woshub.com/get-aduser-getting-active-directory-users-data-via-powershell/

Here, more or less at half page, I found something which seems usefull for me:

> Task: for the list of accounts that are stored in a text file (one
> account per line), you need to get the user’s company name from AD and
> save it to a CSV file (you can easily import this file into Excel).

```
Import-Csv c:\ps\users_list.csv | ForEach {
Get-ADUser -identity $_.user -Properties Name, Company |
Select Name, Company |
Export-CSV c:\ps\users_ad_list.csv -Append -Encoding UTF8
}
```

So, I tried to convert this query for my needs. For Example, I don't need the company, but `UserPrincipalName` and `SamAccountname`.

The point is that when I perform the query, I got an error on -Identity parameter:

```
Get-ADUser : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The argument is null or an element of the argument collection contains a null value.
```

So, I searched again on google but I didin't found a solution; I catch only that the problem is related with use of `$_.users` variable.

So, I have 2 questions:

1. What is the problem with the above code?
2. Many examples I found work giving as input file a list of `SamAccountName`. In case the list is filled with other value, like mines, should I change something in the code?

EDIT: as requested, I share with you few rows of my csv.The name are of course changed for security and privacy reason.

```
Mickey Mouse
Donald Duck
Scrooge McDuck
```

And so on. So, the column is filled with name and surname of people.
I wonder: may be a problem the use of this syntax on other fields?
I mean, the name and surname couple is used not only for `Name` field in my case, but also for other 2 fields: `DisplayName` and another one I don't remember exactely. May be this the root cause?

Comment: You mention that the CSV file only has a `Name` column - but you reference `$_.user`. Try `Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(ANR=$($_.Name))"` instead to search based on the name

Comment: Hi @MathiasR.Jessen, thanks for your suggestion.

I don't know if I performed well your tip: I changed my query in :

`Import-Csv <path file> | ForEach {Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(ANR=$($_.Name))" -Properties * |Select SamAccountName, UserPrincipalName | Export-CSV <path file> -Append -Encoding UTF8}`

But now I have the error `The search filter cannot be recognized`; what I wrong?

Comment: That would be the case if `$_.Name` resolves to an empty string - indicating that maybe `Name` isn't the correct column name either? Can you [update your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68724698/edit) and show us the first few lines from the raw CSV file?

Comment: Sure , I'll we do. Of course, for privacy reason, the name will be changed.

Comment: So your CSV file is not actually a CSV file - it's just a list of names each on their own line? :)

Comment: Yes, you are right. My apologies: with csv I mean the file type, becaus is a .csv file.

Comment: So do `Get-Content C:\ps\users_list.csv |ForEach-Object { Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(ANR=$_)"}`

Answer (score 0):

Solved thanks to @Mathias R. Jessen. Is suggestion is valid: due I have a file whit a single column filled qith name and surname,

```
Get-Content C:\ps\users_list.csv |ForEach-Object { Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(ANR=$_)"
```

is a valid Syntax.